# Verilog Code of Dual Port ROM

Tags: memory, verilog, fpga, system-verilog

I want to write verilog code of Dual port ROM in order to access two addresses simultaneously. I write the verilog code for Single port ROM but can't able to et it for Dual port ROM.

This is my verilog code for sinle port ROM.

```
always @(posedge clk)
 begin
   case(addr)
     3'b000:
     begin
     dout0<=9'b001001001;
     mod70<=001;
     mod50<=001;
     mod30<=001;
     end
     3'b001:
    begin
     dout1<=9'b010010010;
     mod71<=010;
     mod51<=001;
     mod31<=010;
     end
     3'b010:
    begin
     dout2<=9'b100100001;
     mod72<=100;
     mod52<=100;
     mod32<=001;
     end
     3'b011:
    begin
     dout3<=9'b001011010;
     mod73<=001;
     mod53<=011;
     mod33<=010;
     end
     3'b100: 
     begin
     dout4<=9'b010001001;
     mod74<=010;
     mod54<=001;
     mod34<=001;
     end
     3'b101:
    begin
     dout5<=9'b100010010;
     mod75<=100;
     mod55<=010;
     mod35<=010;
     end
     3'b110:
    begin
     dout6<=9'b001100001;
     mod76<=001;
     mod56<=100;
     mod36<=001;
     end
     3'b111:
    begin
     dout7<=9'b010011010;
     mod77<=010;
     mod57<=011;
     mod37<=010;
     end
     endcase
     end
```

Comment: I can see that addr is the address of your ROM, but... which of the doutX registers hold the data you read from an address? There should be one data register. What are these modXX registers? Does this really work as single port ROM?

Comment: Core Generator is the easiest way to generate block memories with your own configurations. The output of Core Generator is a very optimized code without any probable mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 147 of the [Xilinx XST user guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/xst.pdf) you will find examples of RAM and ROM.

They do not provide a dual-port ROM example, but they provide dual-port RAM, and you can omit the write to make it a ROM:

This example is on page 164:

```
module v_rams_11 (clk, a, dpra, spo, dpo);
    input   clk;               
    input   we;                
    input   [5:0] a;           
    input   [5:0] dpra;        
    output  [15:0] spo;        
    output  [15:0] dpo;        
    reg     [15:0] ram [63:0]; 
    reg     [5:0] read_a;      
    reg     [5:0] read_dpra;   

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        read_a <= a;
        read_dpra <= dpra;
    end

    assign spo = ram[read_a];
    assign dpo = ram[read_dpra];
endmodule
```

Comment: Actually whatever code i written above that is for ROM.It is one of the part of my while architecture in which i want to access Addr(i.e address) but i want to access two addresses.and problem is in case i can apply only one addresss.......how to access for another?

Comment: i post my code in which i use ROM for one input but i want the same logic having two input means when i am having both input 'a' and  'b'